# How to read a file's content and search for a string in multiple files

Tags: ruby

I have a text file that has around 100 plus entries like out.txt:

```
domain\1esrt
domain\2345p
yrtfj
tkpdp
....
....
```

I have to read out.txt, line-by-line and check whether the strings like "domain\1esrt" are present in any of the files under a different directory. If present delete only that string occurrence and save the file.

I know how to read a file line-by-line and also know how to grep for a string in multiple files in a directory but I'm not sure how to join those two to achieve my above requirement.

Comment: If you know how to read each line in Ruby, then it's a simple matter of applying the appropriate String class method for matching patterns. Have you looked at the methods in the [Ruby String class documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html)?

Comment: @lurker: Nope, I'm very new to Ruby and already missed my deadline.

Comment: As many other people will state, this is not a homework service.  At least show us what you've tried and where you are stuck; don't expect someone to churn out code for you

Comment: @voltas it doesn't take long to read the documentation, and as has been mentioned, this site is *not* for the purpose of doing your work for you quickly to get a late assignment done.

Comment: Your question isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". We need to see your attempt at solving the problem as evidence of effort. "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822)" is important too. And, just to point it out, SO is the top site on the internet for answering programming questions. If this is homework, you can be sure your instructor is aware of it and knows how to search to see if your solution matches code we supply.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `gsub` here. It will run a regex search on the string and replace it with the second parameter. So if you only have to replace any single string, I believe you can simply run `gsub` on that string (including the newline) and replace it with an empty string:

```
new_file_text = text.gsub(/regex_string\n/, "")
```

Comment: I want an inline edit  , im not allowed to create a new file. is it possible

Comment: The output of that line, what I called `new_file_text`, will be the entire file string with that regex_string removed. So you can simply rewrite to the file.

Comment: Thanks Chris , will try that . Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array with all the words or strings you want to find and then delete/replace:

```
strings_to_delete = ['aaa', 'domain\1esrt', 'delete_me']
```

Then to read the file and use `map` to create an array with all the lines who doesn't match with none of the elements in the array created before:

```
# read the file 'text.txt'
lines = File.open('text.txt', 'r').map do|line|
  # unless the line matches with some value on the strings_to_delete array
  line unless strings_to_delete.any? do |word| 
    word == line.strip 
  end
  # then remove the nil elements
end.reject(&:nil?)
```

And then open the file again but this time to write on it, all the lines which didn't match with the values in the `strings_to_delete` array:

```
File.open('text.txt', 'w') do |line|
  lines.each do |element|
    line.write element
  end
end
```

The `txt` file looks like:

```
aaa
domain\1esrt
domain\2345p
yrtfj
tkpdp
....
....
delete_me
```

I don't know how it'll work with a bigger file, anyways, I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks much, will try.